# Manually including eBay API references with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl, ebay-api

I have been trying to connect to the eBay API by following the tutorial on their website called "API Guide: Executing Your First C# Call". However, I can't seem to build the references.

On the website they state:

> In Visual Studio, create a project file, then add a web reference to it (Solution Explorer, right-click, Add Web Reference). Enter the URL to the latest eBay WSDL:
>
> http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl
>
> Then, click Add Reference. This generates stubs from the eBay WSDL and adds them to the project so that they are available to your source files. You can see them in the Class View.

I can create a web reference, but I cannot do the "Add Reference" part.

**Is there a way to manually insert the source files?**

Comment: Why are you generating your own client from the WSDL and not using the [SDK they provide](https://go.developer.ebay.com/netsdk)?

Comment: WOW. I feel super stupid. I hadn't even thought of that. Thanks for the suggestion!